# Regular expression to get a string between two strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Can you please suggest how to extract {strings between 0} and also when {string at the beginning and covered from right by 0} and {string at the end and covered from left by 0}

```
'1001130001' -> [1,113,1]
'0001130001' -> [113,1]
'0001130000' -> [113]
```

EDIT: I also need to have location of each string. (Match Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = ["1001130001", "0001130001", "0001130000"]
for val in inp:
    matches = re.findall(r'(?<![^0])[^\D0]+(?![^0])', val)
    print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['1', '113', '1']
['113', '1']
['113']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```py
(?<![^0])  assert that what precedes is either zero OR the start of the input
[^\D0]+    match one or more digit characters other than zero
(?![^0])   assert that what follows is either zero OR the end of the input
```

Comment: You got my vote, but isn't this a very convoluted way to write `[1-9]+`? =)

Comment: @JvdV ... unless the OP's actual input is something like `1abc0001230abc3`, i.e. it only wants non zero digits sandwiched between zeroes (and not other characters).  This might explain why my answer was accepted over yours.

Answer (score 4):

I think maybe even without regex:

```
txts = ['1001130001', '0001130001', '0001130000']
for s in txts:
    print(list(map(int, filter(None, s.split('0')))))
```

---

If you must use regex, then try:

```
import re
txts = ['1001130001', '0001130001', '0001130000']
for s in txts:
    print(list(map(int, re.findall(r'[1-9]+', s))))
```

---

Both options return:

```
[1, 113, 1]
[113, 1]
[113]
```

---

***EDIT:***

Since you mentioned you also need the position of the match object, you could use `re.finditer` and some list-comprehension:

```
import re
txts = ['1001130001', '0001130001', '0001130000']
for s in txts:
    print([[m.start(), int(m.group())] for m in re.finditer(r'[1-9]+', s)])
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1], [3, 113], [9, 1]]
[[3, 113], [9, 1]]
[[3, 113]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just want to split by sequences of zero.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('0+', '1001130001')
['1', '113', '1']
```

In order to not end up with empty results you can preprocess your string with `str.strip`.

```
>>> re.split('0+', '0001130000')
['', '113', '']
>>> re.split('0+', '0001130000'.strip('0'))
['113']
```